# DVD Rom doesn't read bootable DVDs

Tags: dvd, bootable-media

I am using an ASUS K50l with a windows 7 home premium. My DVD Rom reads DVDs normally, a bit laggy but does its job.
However when it comes to bootable disks it identifies them as blank DVDs.
Is there a way to fix this?
I need to boot from a Windows 7 Home Premium DVD in order to fix the dual boot problem I am having.
But there was one Windows 7 Ultimate DVD that worked just fine for me but was not what I needed.
Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Is the BIOS set with the DVD/CD drive ahead of the hard drive in the boot order?

Comment: 1) Was the one DVD which worked a original (pressed) DVD, and are the others burned recordables?  2) Does your DVD player read both DVD+R and DVD-R disks? (most modern ones do, if it is old it might not). 3) Did you change SATA cables? (Sounds insane, but my computer will not boot from DVD if I connect it to the intel hosted ports. If works if I connect to the the extra SATA ports of anopther chip. Though that might be a BIOS bug on my board).

Comment: 1)Nope, it wasn't, but it was of no use for me since I needed a Home Premium edition to erase BackTrack 5.
2)Dunno about DVD+R, but certainly DVD-R.
3)Can I change this in my laptop?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not download a Windows 7 ISO, unzip it, and copy that to a USB thumbdrive? Then you can just boot from the flashdrive.

Official Windows 7 ISOs(legal):
http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/

create bootable flashdrive with windows 7:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/creating-windows-7-install-media-on-flash-drive/5eb58e71-52e6-47c8-91a0-a795a7d49356

Comment: Thanks I'll try this at night (free download :P), and I'll keep you up with any further updates.